# Probabilities to end up in certain state

Tags: probability

I have 6 steps with a certain probability. Let say:

- step > probability
- 0 > 0.5
- 1 > 0.1
- 2 > 0.1
- 3 > 0.1
- 4 > 0.1
- 5 > 0.05
- 6 > 0.05

This table presents a number of moves that I have to do in a next step, this means, if I get 3 I am moving 3 positions forward, if I get 5, I have to move 5 positions forward and with 0 I will quit the game. My maximum number of steps is 15 and I quit the game in two cases: or if I get 0, or if I reach the value 15.

Here is an example 1:

- I get 4 > going to position 4
- I get 2 > going to position 6
- I get 6 > going to position 12
- I get 1 > going to position 13
- I get 2 or more > going to position 15
- The game is finished!

Example 2:

- I get 2 > going to position 2
- I get 2 > going to position 4
- I get 1 > going to position 5
- I get 0 > staying at position 5 and the game is finished.

Can someone explain me, how to calculate the expected probability to be in all states between 0 and 15? I would like to have a table like:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\text{state} & 0& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4& 5&... & 14 & 15 \\ \hline
\text{prob} &0.1& 0.01 &0.011&0.03&0.2&0.25&...& 0.0001 &0.00001& \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Thanks for help!

Comment: As a quick hint. I would view the proces as a Markovian process. Don't get scared of the word. It just means that at time $0$ you are always in state $0$. Then you look one step further and see with what probability you are where. Then, examine state $1$ and update. Continue until you arrive at state $15$ :)

Comment: The probability to be in each state under what circumstances? A particular number of steps of the game? The end state of the game? (All of these can be answered using the theory of Markov chains and some linear algebra.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll construct a markov matrix that looks like this (assuming that if you cross 15, you win):
[image]

This markov matrix has two absorbing states, 0 and 15. Now, use the method detailed in section 7.3 here: https://ryu577.github.io/jekyll/update/2018/10/08/competitive_coin_tossing.html to get the probabilities of the state ending up in 0 or 15 (losing/winning; the two absorbing states).

Comment: Rohit Pandey, thanks for your answer, but I do not understand you matrix. Why did you set first column with 0.5? and first row as well, shouldn't be like 0.5, 0.1,0.1,0.,0.1,0.05,0.05,0,0,0,0,0,0... because from state 0 you can go 1 till 6 positions forward.
My version of matrix looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21nLV.png

Comment: I might have misunderstood the rules of your game. I thought if you get a zero at any step, you start over. If it means you just stay where you are, then your matrix is accurate. But you can see how Markov chains are very versatile and can be used to model any such game.

Comment: In your matrix, your markov chain has just one absorbing state, so in the long run, the process will be in that absorbing state. Hence, the probability of being in any other state will tend to zero and that of being in the absorbing state will tend to 1.

Comment: If you want instead you want the probability of being in each state after n steps, you just construct the vector of the initial state and multiply the matrix with it n times.

Comment: That was my first matrix and I don't think is correct bacause 0 is not absorbing state.  If you get a 0 at any step, it means you just stay where you are. Con you please explain  why did you set up you matrix in this way? especially first column and row. I bild my matrix in a way that I am checking for each row where I am going in next step.

Comment: I set it up like that because I mistakenly thought $0$ was an absorbing state.

Comment: You said that when you get $0$, you would quit the game. That seems to suggest $0$ is an absorbing state.

Comment: Zero is an absorbing state. Like I described in example 2: if I get zero, then I stay at position 5 and the game is finished.
My solution is the following:
First  I moved zero state below and in this case I have identity matrix (orange color). https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxUjm.png

next step: I-Q https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNmzd.png

Final matrix: The first line in my final matrix is the expected number of visits for each state. In average I will play 1,917385 games (the sum of first line) https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sPR9.png